# Can I send an obj of a class to a file using filestream in C#?

Tags: c#, io, filestream

I was wondering if I can send a whole obj which has 4 members:

```
string name
string lastname
int StudentID
int CitizenID
```

using the filestream commends to save in a .txt file in binary format?

I know of Serialization, and it sends an obj to a .xml file quite easily, but when I made my program using it and showed it to my teacher, he said he don't want me to use it, said I have to use the base filestream commands like `fstream`, `instream`, `outstream` and ... in C++ , and told me he want a binary format saved .txt file.

Now my question is, can I send a whole obj to a .txt file in C# or do i have to send it like a string, which will be quite a lot of work.

Because I have to turn all members to string then put a indicator or something at end of each so I can read from them later and separate them.

Comment: He wants it done in C++, not C#? That's an important first part to clarify. Your question is tagged C#, and you ask if you can send an object to a text file in C#, but if your teacher will just say "No, I told you to do it in C++", what good is any help you get here? Please clarify: Do you need this done in C# or C++?

Comment: And I question the validity of saving to a binary format and appending a .TXT file extension. You will not be able to open up the file and read it correctly in, say, notepad, if you use a binary serialization mechanism. All files are binary, they're made up of bytes. Having a .TXT extension is a *signal* that tells a program that this file, made up of bytes, can in some way be interpreted as text made up of characters. But just appending .TXT doesn't make it text or readable.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , Hey , he Don't want it in C++ , he said do it anywhere u want , but he was our C++ teacher before this class , and so he told me i want u to use the fstream instream outstream and such that u used in C++ or equalization of them in C# for ur program , and make binary .txt file not .xml

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and yeh , i know i won't be able to open it in notepad or such , but i should be able to open it again with my program so i can search the records and edit or delete them if needed .

Comment: @Pedram note: editing and deleting inside a file (without re-writing the entire file) is not as simple as you might think, and if that is an actual requirement you need to design it for that. For example, fixed-length records, or padding, and probably logical deletion flags. Or logically delete (set one bit) and append to end of file, etc.

Comment: i know it is not easy, and i did asked my teacher, what he said was u need to put a string as a flag or something to indicate the end of each record , so later u can search by it and now when each record ended . and as if this all is not hard enough he want it to be in binary ....

Answer (score 1):

> now my question is , can i send a whole obj to a .txt file in C# or do i have to send it like a string ... which will be quite a lot of work ,

Yes, there is a name for this: serialization. Whether you do it manually in your own code, or using one of a range of existing serialization libraries, it is serialization. If your teacher doesn't want you using a serialization library, then you would have to do it in your own code. Which is frankly stupid. I wonder if the teacher wants you to write raw commands to the hard disk as well, to avoid all those silly abstractions like a HAL, OS, or common class libraries...

It may be worth clarifying with your teacher exactly what is, and is not, acceptable. For example, would a binary serializer suffice? I could name several. Would it be OK to use `BinaryWriter` / `BinaryReader`? Or is the intent of the exercise to make you think about *what you need to do to serialize/deserialize*? If the latter: then yes, learn about streams, encodings, and framing protocols (sentinel-values vs length-prefixed data, etc).

Comment: Yes, i know of Serialization, i think My teacher wants .txt binary file ,  he was cool with it till he figure it produce .xml file ,  he told me to make a binary .txt file to have my studentrecords saved on it ,  
the Whole Question is making a program that take student records , and save it to a files , then search it , edit it , delete it , and when i ask him how to make them separated , he said make a string and print it as last line in each record , so u know it ended and new record started , like double 00  or something ,

Comment: "My teacher wants .txt binary file" - basically, allow me to echo everything Lasse already said; that phrase alone makes me cringe. But indeed, if the idea is for you to learn about writing data to files, go do that.

Comment: btw i don't know exactly what this class i have is called in English but if u translate it word by word it will be :   Storage and retrieval of Data

Comment: lol i meant my Teacher want a something.txt file that have the data written in it in binary format ,
     in C++ u would add something like IOS:Binary or something at end of it and it would save as binary !

Comment: @Pedram yep, I understood what you meant; it is just a silly requirement that your teacher has. Sure, there's nothing *magical* about the `.txt` extension that means it **must** contain some kind of encoded text, but; it is a nice simple convention that everyone understands. Except, it seems, your teacher.

Comment: so what do u think i should do ? he gave us 2 week time , first week i went and learn serialization and finish half my program using it , then he told me he want .txt and binary ! now it's due Saturday Sigh :| how do i even make a .txt in binary in C# ? i tried searching for it on msdn found the normal format , but not binary one :|

Comment: @Pedram you take a `Stream` (`File.Create(...)`, for example), and then you `.Write(...)` to it. That's it. Nothing magic. Of course, you might choose to use helper utilities, but frankly I don't: they don't really help much, and they are likely to irritate your teacher just as much. The only *real* thing you need to figure out is: what should the binary contents **look like**. What is the format you are writing? (that is rhetorical: you don't need to answer that to me; you just need to figure it out before you start writing)

Comment: hmm wouldn't the Stream File.create(...) .Write(...) make a .txt in normal characters ? not binary ?  i think i used one and send a string from a text box to it , it would just make a .txt and when i open it , it show the word i written , not binary.  while in C++ IOS:Binary would make the .txt file not readable

Comment: @Pedram The `Stream.Write()` method takes a `byte[]` (plus offset/count). It will look like whatever you tell it to look like. If you happen to write bytes that are text-like (ascii, utf-8, etc), then it will by coincidence also look like a text file - all text files are binary; not all binary is text. If you write data that is not text, it will not look like text.

Comment: Oh ! Dang , things is getting complicated , specially when these teachers make up weird requirements , wish i could just used the easiest methods which are already implanted with some includes :P Tnx anyway for now i try to see how far i can get :D

Comment: sorry i have to ask something again , Can i Seek or any other way Search and Find an student ID or name and then read from where ?  for example i got a studentrecord.txt with several studentrecords in them , they all start with student ID and end with "END"  and have 3 "space" between each part , can i move the pointer to the one starting with 91125384 and then Read it ?  i know seek can move me to a byte position but idk how to find the position of a character in my file :| if all not work i just have to read it all in a string then search for it which is gonna be not really good.

Comment: @Pedram nope, not unless you provide for that in your protocol. A file position is just an offset. For example, consider a CD. What does "move to track 9" mean? It only has meaning because there is some index data that makes it possible to define track 9. Without that, you have to search manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this...

```
void saveInBinary()
{
    IFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream binaryStream = new FileStream("File Path Here", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(binaryStream, this);
    binaryStream.Close();
}
```

Stick that in the object's member space, and just call it.

Or, something a bit more useful...

```
void saveInBinary(object o)
{
    IFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream binaryStream = new FileStream("File Path Here", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(binaryStream, o);
    binaryStream.Close();
}
```

This will serialize any object passed to it.

Last variation (I promise!) :p

```
void saveInBinary(object o, string filePath)
{
    IFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream binaryStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(binaryStream, o);
    binaryStream.Close();
}
```

This one allows you to pass an object and a filepath to the method to serialize the passed object to the passed filepath.

Of course, this will not allow you to read the contents of the .txt file. It'll look like mumbo jumbo. If your intent is to write the data to a human readable file, well, there are tons of examples for that. :p I just provided the serialization stuff because it took me a while to figure it out. ;)

Edit: Shoot. I forgot some code...

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
```

Code needs those to work (for the IFormatter) Also, for Stream to work, you need to use

```
using System.IO;
```

Sorry for forgetting.

Edit 2: Forgot to mention, you'll need to use the [Serializeable] tag on the object(s) you wish to serialize this way. Just put "[Serializeable]" on top of the class you want to serialize.

```
[Serializeable]
class SerializeableObject
{
    string aString;

    void aMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Like so.

Comment: Hey man , sorry for late reply ,  your code seems good , i actually want a file in a mundo jumbo non readable style ,  but  i got few unhandled exception and such at the run , i passed them and it worked tho , but with what code can i now retrieve this and read back my obj from this file and use it in the program ?

Comment: Fixed the errors , needed [Serializable] and [NonSerializable] codes for my class.

Comment: Woops, sorry. I forgot to include that. I've fixed that now, haha. Sorry about that.